# What does the "T" stand for in T-duality?

Tags: string-theory, soft-question, terminology, duality

First of all, I am not a physicist. I'm a graduate math student and recently I came across the concept of [T-duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-duality). Actually I'm studying generalized complex geometry, which according to this paper ([Generalized complex geometry and T-duality](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1747)) can be used to get some nice interpretations of T-duality.

After reading some of it, I thought the "T" stand for torus, because the the fiber are torus. But then I found another paper ([Spherical T-duality](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5844)) defining T-duality for $SU(2)$-bundles. At first I asked myself "Why keep calling it T-duality, if the fiber are not torus anymore?" Probably it means something else...

So, what does the "T" stand for in T-duality?

Comment: It is probably just historical -- when it was first discovered “T" was for torus (strings compactified on torus/cylinder).

Comment: Related meta post: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451

Answer (score 4):

The name [T-duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-duality) stands for *Target-space duality,* *Topological duality,* or *Toroidal duality,* depending on whom you ask. See e.g. [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9503226) preprint or [this](https://www.dummies.com/education/science/physics/string-theory-duality/) book.

Comment: Reminds me of Witten's answer when he was asked what the 'M' in M-theory stands for :)

Answer (score 2):

T duality and S duality come from the $T$ transformation and $S$ transformation which generate the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from [S matrix theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix_theory), long before  quarks were imagined, S,T and U characterize the type of exchange in the Feynman diagrams entering the S matrix calculation, and they are called [Mandelstam variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelstam_variables).

[image: s channel] [image: t channel] [image: u channel]

s channel-------------------------- t channel------------------------u channel

duality meant that the sums could be done either in S channel or T channel and the result should be the same.

There is a resurrection of the scattering matrix for strings and I guess the definition has morphed to what you find in the link you gave.

[It is also used](http://inspirehep.net/record/1087044?ln=en) in nuclear physics, where dualities are useful.

The above is history of theory in particle physics, and it was T because it came after the S of Scattering ( like y after x).