# What S means in S-duality?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, gauge-theory, yang-mills, duality

As I know, there are many dualities related to [S-duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-duality). For example, Montonen-Olive duality, Seiberg duality. and so on.
so, I wonder that what "S" means in the term "S-duality".
If this is a stupid question, I am really sorry.

Comment: S-duality is a duality between strong coupling and weak coupling, so I'd guess  it comes from the "strong", as in "strong-weak".

Comment: Related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173020/2451

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from Joseph Polchinski's book [String Theory Vol 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052167228).

> **S-duality** : a duality under which the coupling constant of a quantum theory changes nontrivially, including the case of weak-strong duality. Important examples are the $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ self-dualities of IIB string theory and $d = 4, N = 4$ supersymmetric Yang-Mills theory. More loosely, it is used for weak-strong dualities between different theories,$\ldots$.

S-duality is a duality concerning the coupling constant (i.e. strength of interaction). The strong coupling limit of one theory is equivalent to the weak coupling limit of another  theory. The S here stands for the *strong* as appear in weak-strong duality.

The origin of this term probably stems from the dualities in the s-, t- and u-channel in scattering matrices. There are other type of dualities
which is named following this s/t/u pattern.

- T-duality - a duality concerning the length scale, usually in a toroidally compactified theory.

  For an example, consider a closed string living on a space where one of its dimensions has been compactified to a torus of radius $R$. Its momentum along that dimension is quantized. Its mass contains a term $\propto \frac{n}{R}$ which $n$ is the level of excitation along the direction.

  The string can also wrap around that dimension with a winding number $w$. The tension of the string contribute another part $\propto wR$ to the mass.

  In the limit of small and large geometry ( $R \to 0$ vs $R \to \infty$), these two pieces $\frac{n}{R}$ and $wR$ can exchange their role and relate the physics on different end.
- U-duality - a "unified" duality, a duality that is neither an S- nor a T-duality.

  For example, a transformation that exchanges a large geometry of one  theory with the strong coupling of another theory.

Answer (score 0):

See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-duality). It is probable the "S" stands for Spanier as in [Edwin Spanier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Spanier).

Comment: I like how that Wikipedia article suggests a power series $A_0 + A_1g + A_2g^2 + A_3g^3+\cdots$ will not converge unless $|g| < 1$. As if the coefficients do not play a role in the matter.

Comment: @KCd physicists.